# Python decoding bytes object returns an empty string

Tags: python-3.x

Excuse me if this is a duplicate. I've searched a lot before posting this and actually found many similar posts, but couldn't solve my problem yet.

I'm trying to decode a bytes object in python 3.8 and keep failing.

The bytesObject object is like this

`b'January,February,March\n0,3,0\n'`

and `print(type(bytesObject))` shows <class 'bytes'>.

All the below return an empty string, what am I missing here?

```
bytesObject.decode("UTF-8")
str(bytesObject)
str(bytesObject.decode())
repr(bytesObject)
repr(bytesObject.decode())
bytesObject.text
```

Its text encoding is certainly UTF-8.

I also tried csv reader and json converters too but still no success.

Comment: Works for me: [demo](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P6myJLXYPykrNblEwVYhSd0rMa80sahSxy01qQjM8E0sSs6IyTPQMdYxiMlT5@IqKMrMK9EoqSxI1UDSrKkJlUAS00tJTc5PSdVQCg1x07VQ0tT8/x8A).  Where is `bytesObject` being set?  Is it being accessed elsewhere?

Comment: Thanks, it’s a response from some external API from which I get an HTTPResponse object. The bytes object is `bytesObject = Response.read()`. I'm accessing the object within the same class, same function, just below the line.